# How many solutions does a consistent linear system of three equations and four unknowns have? Why?

Tags: linear-algebra

$4$ vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ yield $3$ equations in $4$ variables.

At most only $3$ of the vectors will be independent in $\mathbb R^3$. So $4$ vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ span $\mathbb R^3$ if $3$ of the $4$ vectors are independent.

If only $2$ of the vectors are independent, they span a plane in $\mathbb R^3.$

If all the vectors are dependent, they span a line in $\mathbb R^3.$

In every case above the line, plane and $\mathbb R^3$ contain infinite number of points. Since there are no more cases, we can say that $3$ equations in $4$ unknowns will have infinite number of solutions.

Do you agree? Thanks.

Comment: System could be inconsistent $x+y+z+w=0$ and $x+y+z+w=1$. The third equation can be anything.

Comment: Thanks @AnuragA. The problem says that the system is consistent. In that case, do you agree with what I posted, though?

Comment: What are you considering as variables?

Comment: @mfl, for variables I am considering any scalar that multiplies one of the vectors.

Comment: The 4 variables live in $\mathbb{R}^4.$ So, in my opinion, you have to modify a bit your argument. I mean, you say "the line, plane and $\mathbb{R}^3$ contain infinite number of points". But this infinite number of points are not the unknowns.

Comment: @mfl, you're right the lines and planes contain the vectors, not the scalars. How can I redo my argument?

Comment: You are in the right direction. Once you have a solution, that must exist because the four vectors are linearly dependent, then any multiple is a solution. Thus you get that there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: $2$ independent $4D$ vectors span a plane in $\mathbb R^4 : (a, b, c, d) \cdot (x, y, z, w) = ax + by + cz + dw = $ constant. Smallest dimension at which planes intersect is a line, but the line contains infinite number of points, so that there are infinite number of solutions. Does this sound better?